# How do I to flatMap a Try[Option] in an idiomatic way

Tags: scala

I want to flatMap a Try[Option[A]] using some function that uses the value inside the Option to create another Try, and I want the solution to be simple and idiomatic. I have illustrated the problem with an example. The goal is to create a Option[Group] with members and events wrapped in a single Try that can contain errors from any of the three functions.

```
def getGroup(id: Long): Try[Option[Group]]

def getMembersForGroup(groupId: Long): Try[Seq[Member]]

def getMeetingsForGroup(groupId: Long): Try[Seq[Meeting]]
```

I find it difficult to flatMap from the Try returned by `getGroup` to the Try from the member- and meeting-functions because there's an Option "in the way". This is what i have come up with so far:

```
getGroup(id).flatMap(
  groupOpt => groupOpt.map(
    group => addStuff(group).map(group => Some(group))
  ).getOrElse(Success(None))
)

def addStuff(g: Group): Try[Group] =
  for {
    members <- getMembersForGroup(g.id)
    meetings <- getMeetingsForGroup(g.id)
  } yield g.copy(members = members, meetings = meetings)
```

What I don't like about my solution is that I have to wrap the group returned by `addStuff` in an Option to perform the getOrElse. At this point the type is Option[Try[Option[Group]]] which I think makes the solution difficult to understand at first glance.

Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: How are you combining the three? Into what type? Should I assume you have a function `(Seq[Member], Seq[Meeting], Group) => ResultType` for some ResultType?

Comment: I use the copy function yielded by the for-comprehension. I want the resulting type to be Try[Option[Group]].

Comment: Based on reading the title of this question, I recommend reading https://www.manning.com/books/functional-and-reactive-domain-modeling!

Answer (score 3):

Cats has an `OptionT` type that might simplify this: [documentation here](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) and [source here](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/OptionT.scala).

Your example would be:

```
def getGroupWithStuff(id: Long): OptionT[Try, Group] = {
  for {
    g <- OptionT(getGroup(id))
    members <- OptionT.liftF(getMembersForGroup(g.id))
    meetings <- OptionT.liftF(getMeetingsForGroup(g.id))
  } yield g.copy(members = members, meetings = meetings)
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, flatMapF to add members and meetings rather than lifting.

Comment: This looks like the most clean solution, however I feel that introducing the concept of OptionT overall makes the solution more complex. I think I would like a more "vanilla" kind of solution.

Comment: I can definitely understand that. Not always worth introducing a new library to solve one small problem. Just wanted to provide one more option (no pun intended).

Comment: just gonna add that this is also a traverse inside a flatmap

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.fold` instead of `.map.getOrElse` ... That makes it a little bit nicer:

```
 getGroup(id)
   .flatMap { 
     _.fold(Try(Option.empty[Group])){ 
       addStuff(_).map(Option.apply) 
     }
   }
```

or write the two cases explicitly -  that may look a little clearer in this case, because you can avoid having to spell out the ugly looking type signature:

```
  getGroup(id).flatMap {
    case None => Success(None)
    case Some(group) => addStuff(group).map(Option.apply)
  }
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to get rid of the Option.apply which is what i really wanted, but it might not be possible. However using flatMap with patternMatching is an improvement though.

Comment: You could push wrapping into `Option` down to `addStuff` I guess ... the point is it has to happen somewhere, because the the types are different. I have made an implicit `.toOption` in my project for this sort of things, so that I could just write `yield g.copy(members = members, meetings = meetings).toOption` as the last line of `addStuff` (hate nested parentheses :)).

Answer (score 0):

You probably could simplify your getGroup call to:

```
  getGroup(id).map(
    groupOpt => groupOpt.flatMap(
      group => addStuff(group).toOption
    )
  )
```

, however that would be at cost of ignoring potential failure info from addStuff call. If it is not acceptable then it is unlikely you could simplify your code further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You get to keep your for comprehension syntax as well as Failure information from any of the three calls (whichever fails first).

```
def getFullGroup(id: Long): Try[Option[Group]] =
  getGroup(id).flatMap[Option[Group]] { _.map[Try[Group]]{ group =>
    for {
      meetings <- getMeetingsForGroup(id)
      members  <- getMembersForGroup
    } yield group.copy(meetings = meetings, members = members)
  }.fold[Try[Option[Group]]](Success(None))(_.map(Some(_)))
}
```

Note the type acrobatics at the end:

`fold[Try[Option[Group]]](Success(None))(_.map(Some(_)))`

It's hard to get right without type annotations and an IDE. In this particular case, that's not too bad, but imagine meetings and members depended on another nested try option which in turn depended on the original. Or imagine if you wanted to a comprehension on individual Meetings and Groups rather than using the entire list.

You can try using an OptionT monad transformer from cats or scalaz to stack `Try[Option[Group]]` into a non-nested `OptionT[Try, Group]`. If you use a monad transformer, it can look like this:

```
def getFullGroup(id: Long): OptionT[Try, Group] =
  OptionT(getGroup(id)).flatMapF { group =>
    for {
      meetings <- getMeetingsForGroup(id)
      members  <- getMembersForGroup(id)
    } yield group.copy(meetings = meetings, members = members)
  }
}
```

For this particular case, there's not really much gain. But do look into it if you have a lot of this kind of code.

By the way, the boilerplate at the end of the first example that flips the Try and Option is called a `sequence`. When it follows a map, the whole thing is called `traverse`. It's a pattern that comes up often and is abstracted away by functional programming libraries. Instead of using OptionT, you can do something like:

```
def getFullGroup(id: Long): Try[Option[Group]] =
  getGroup(id).flatMap[Option[Group]] { _.traverse { group =>
    for {
      meetings <- getMeetingsForGroup(id)
      members  <- getMembersForGroup
    } yield group.copy(meetings = meetings, members = members)
  }
}
```

(Generally, if you're mapping `f` then flipping monads, you want to traverse with `f`.)